# Typscript: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string | { value: string; label: string; }

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't figure out why Typescript is marking this as an error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string | { value: string; label: string; }'.
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.
Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string | { value: string; label: string; }'.  
Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Code implementation:

```
type KeyParams="email"|"username"|"password"|"country"
type InputParams = Record<KeyParams, {error:boolean,value:string|{value: string, label: string}, msg:string}>
```

Inside React functional component:

```
const [inputs, setInputParams] = useState<InputParams>({"email":{error:false,value:"",msg:""},"username":{error:false,value:"",msg:""},"password":{error:false,value:"",msg:""},"country":{error:false,value:{value:"",label:""},msg:""}})
...
<input type="hidden" name="country" value={inputs.country.value.value}/>
                           <div className="w-100 h-100 relative flex items-center">
                                   ...
                                   <span className="nowrap">{inputs.country.value.label}</span>
```

It doesn't mark that error when I only write the value `inputs.country.value` inside the  input and span elements
Couldn't find any similar question/solution for this specific case. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you type the state variable as `InputParams` typescript allows you to change the state to something like `"country": { error: false, value: '', msg: "" }`, and then `value` doesn't have `value` property anymore, since it would be a string. Either remove the `useState` type parameter, use discriminated unions to type create your InputParams type so that `country` can only be of `value: { value: "", label: "" }` or create a type guard to chack the `value` type before using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roberto explained in their comment, the problem is that `inputs.country.value` could be *either* an object `{ value: string; label: string; }` or just a plain `string`.  That's because of how you've defined your `InputParams` type:

```
type InputParams = Record<KeyParams, {
    error: boolean,
    value: string | {value: string, label: string}, // <-- this union right here
    msg: string
}>
```

But in your actual component, `inputs.country.value` is always the object.

This is a case where you're better off letting TypeScript infer the types for you.  You'll get accurate type checking if you drop the generic `<InputParams>` on your `useState` hook:

```
const [inputs, setInputParams] = useState({"email":{error:false, ...
```

When you don't specify the state type, TypeScript will base it off of the initial value.  So since you set the initial value for `country` to `{error:false,value:{value:"",label:""},msg:""}`, TypeScript infers the type of `inputs.country.value` as

```
{ value: string; label: string; }
```

The type `InputParams` is broader than the inferred type, so you are inadvertently widening the type.